# Start downloading file using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to start file downloading when I clicked the button.
I just have the path of the file.
How can I start downloading?
This is what I tried so far:

```
$('#download_button').click(function(){

    var filepath = $(this).attr('data-filepath');
    var do = '<a href="'+ filepath +'" download="file">file</a>';
    $(body).append(do);
});
```

What I am doing wrong.
I never want to redirect the page.
Is downloading start in browser or in software for downloading files if installed on client machine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively you can also set the `top.location`

```
$('#download_button').click(function(){
    var filepath = $(this).attr('data-filepath');
    top.location.href = filepath;
});
```

Comment: i have installed IDM why file never start downloading in IDM .Instead of this it start downloading in the browser

Comment: I am unsure why Internet Download Manager won't download the file.  Perhaps make sure you are sending the correct headers as mentioned by Niet in their answer.

Comment: this code work fine on localhost but on my server when i click the download button it open the complete file as text in the browser

Comment: It really depends on which backend you are using to server the file.  Have a look for documentation on the "headers" and or modules for your server (apache/tomcat etc) and if you are generating a file in a scripted language such as PHP look for specific examples of such.

Comment: What is `top.location`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot force a file to be downloaded in JavaScript.

What you can do is `location.href = "somefile.ext";`, however it will *only* be downloaded if the *server* includes `Content-Disposition: attachment` as one of its response headers to that file request.

Comment: what you suggest Niet. i have tried `location.href` and my  file is xml file with custom extension.so when i click the button instead of start downloading it display complete file as text with in the browser

Comment: Configure your server to send the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header for files with your custom extension.

Comment: and how can i do this

Comment: Depends on your server.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download a file to the client, then do this:

```
$('#download_button').click(function(){
    var filepath = $(this).attr('data-filepath');
    location.href = filepath;
});
```

`location.href` will look for a page, but it will not find anything, so it will download the file instead.

Comment: i try your code it open a new window and after that close that and prompt for downloading

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form using jQuery and use the submit function. This will not change the URL in the address bar.

```
$('#download_button').click(function(){

        var filepath = $(this).attr('data-filepath');
        var form = $('<form>').attr('action', filepath);
        form.submit();
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me using MVC at the server. Please, try to specify the http method for the form, change $('<form>') to $('<form method="GET">') or $('<form method="POST">') depending on the method you use. Also make sure that the file path is reachable.